# Como obtener el ARN user pool desde AWS CLI

Tags: aws

como puedo obtener desde AWS CLI el Pool ARN, o el account id de un user pool que he creado.

gracias

Answer (score 0):

```
aws configure

aws cognito-idp list-user-pools --max-results 5
```

Indicando en max-results el número de pools que quieres que te liste. Para cada pool te retorna un conjunto de atributos entre los cuales se encuentra el id.

También puedes encontrar el id directamente desde consola, accediendo al servicio cognito y entrando en la user pool en cuestión.